# Complex Number finding the general Value of Theta

Tags: complex-numbers

If $$(\cos\Theta+i\sin\Theta)(\cos2\Theta+i\sin2\Theta)(\cos3\Theta+i\sin3\Theta) \dots (\cos n\Theta+i\sin n\Theta)=i $$ 
then show that general Value of $$\Theta=\left[2r+\frac1{n(n+1)}\right]\pi$$
$$OR$$

$$\Theta = \frac{\pi+4\pi m}{n(n+1)} $$
How to get the value of theta

Comment: Use $$(\cos A+i\sin A)(\cos B+i\sin B)=\cos(A+B)+i\sin(A+B)$$

Comment: It would be then $cos(\theta+2\theta+3\theta+..n\theta)+isin(\theta+2\theta+3\theta+..n\theta)$ where $$\theta+2\theta+3\theta+..n\theta=\frac{n\theta(n\theta+1)}2$$

Comment: You have a mistake in $$\theta+2\theta+3\theta+..n\theta=\frac{n\theta(n\theta+1)}2$$ It should be $$\frac{1}{2} \theta  n (n+1)$$

Comment: Are you sure your formula is correct? Is $r$ a real number or a natural number?

Comment: r is a natural Number ...I am able to reach this far

$$(\cos\Theta+i\sin\Theta)(\cos2\Theta+i\sin2\Theta)(\cos3\Theta+i\sin3\Theta) \dots (\cos n\Theta+i\sin n\Theta)=i$$ $$\therefore cos(\theta+2\theta+3\theta+..n\theta)+isin(\theta+2\theta+3\theta+..n\theta)=i$$ where$$\theta+2\theta+3\theta+..n\theta=\frac{1}{2} \theta  n (n+1)$$ 
$$\therefore L.H.S=cos(\frac{1}{2}\theta  n (n+1))+isin(\frac{1}{2} \theta  n (n+1))$$
Now R.H.S: 
$$i=cos(\frac12{4r\pi+\pi})+isin(\frac12{4r\pi+\pi}) $$ [where r= 0,1,2,3,...]
$$\therefore$$
  $$\frac{1}{2} \theta  n (n+1)=\frac12{4r\pi+\pi}$$

Comment: Using that $\cos(k\Theta)+i\sin(k\Theta)=e^{ik\Theta}$ we have 

$\begin{array}{ccc}
e^{i\Theta}e^{i2\Theta}e^{i3\Theta}\dots e^{in\Theta} & = & i\\
e^{i\Theta(1+2+3+\dots+n)} & = & i\\
e^{i\Theta\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)} & = & i
\end{array}
 $

Which is only true if (for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$)

$\begin{array}{ccc}
\Theta\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) & = & \frac{1}{2}\pi+2\pi m\\
\Theta n(n+1) & = & \pi+4\pi m\\
\Theta & = & \frac{\pi+4\pi m}{n(n+1)}
\end{array}
 $

I don't see how $\Theta$ could be anything else. Hopefully someone else can chime in on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by  john.abraham, the product can be written as an exponential raised to some sum which can then be equated to $\left({\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi m}\right)i$ (the exponent of $i = e^{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi m\right)i}$)--the $i$'s cancel:

$$
\prod_{k = 1}^{n}\left(\cos\left(k\theta\right) + i\sin\left(k\theta\right)\right) = \prod_{k = 1}^n e^{k\theta i} = i = e^{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi m\right)i} \\
\prod_{k = 1}^n e^{k\theta i} = \exp\left(\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \left(k\theta i\right)\right) \\
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \left(k\theta i\right) = \left(\theta \left(\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k\right)\right)i = \left(\theta \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}\right)i = \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi m\right)i \\
\theta \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi m \\
\theta = \frac{\pi + 4\pi m}{n(n+1)} \text{, q.e.d.}
$$

Comment: This is essentially what john.abraham posted in the comments on 7 April, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I would agree he stated the same thing.

Comment: Then may I suggest that the polite thing to do is to acknowledge it in your post.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree (and there's no way to prove this) except that I wrote this without looking at the comments--I don't know why this came up as a "new" question considering how old the comments are.

Comment: Irrelevant. You have looked at the comments now, you should acknowledge prior work. (And, in the future, I'd recommend reading the comments before posting.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson I appreciate your criticism of conduct and hopefully my edited acknowledgement alleviates that.  It's one of those things where a cursory glance of a comment doesn't seem clear to me so I write my own solution which, after-the-fact, is clear to be the same as the comment.  Hopefully the OP can see that the two explanations are equivalent.